# How does Android source building #ifdefs work in compilation

Tags: android, c++, c, android-source

I'm familiar with Android kernel programming but I'm a newbie at building the Android source. I'm wondering how to enable the #ifdefs in android source building. Are there any defconfig file in android source  like in android  kernel to choose what we want to compile in the compilation?.. How can i enable the codings defined with #ifdef to get compile during the Android source compilation?

Ex:

```
#ifdef USE_ION
    int alloc_map_ion_memory(OMX_U32 buffer_size,
              OMX_U32 alignment, struct ion_allocation_data *alloc_data,
              struct ion_fd_data *fd_data,int flag);
    void free_ion_memory(struct vdec_ion *buf_ion_info);

#else

    bool align_pmem_buffers(int pmem_fd, OMX_U32 buffer_size,
                            OMX_U32 alignment);
#endif
```

I want to make sure the ion  part is being compiled not the pmem part.

Comment: I find no meaning in what you wrote, I'm sorry. Please rephrase.

Comment: They would be set by a /D (for define) in the make file I would suppose.

Comment: Question is clear: the poster wants to know what drives the various build-time defines in the **userspace** portions of Android, vs the (android) **kernel** sources they are more familiar with.

Comment: @MarcoA.  Can my question be reopened?

Comment: Nominated for reopening, now it's surely more answerable. Thanks for editing

Comment: @NickT  you mean the Android.mk file or?

Answer (score 0):

Try add the line:

```
#error "USE_ION"
```

after #ifdef USE_ION

Build again, if the build failed, USE_ION is defined.